# Kafka stream : join value into an array

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka stream which completes missing values from KTable (leftjoin do that perfectly).
But sometimes, I have to make a join for each value into an array and I don't know how to do that correctly.

For example (I take a family) :

```
{father: idFather, mother : idMother, children:[{child: id1},{child: id2}]
```

I'm able to make a join with a Ktable to find father and mother names (join on id).
But for children, I don't know how to loop on each child into the array (I don't know how many child there are).

Currently I create new KStreams for each child :
`stream.flatMapValues(value -> value.get("children"))` and I make the join for each child.
Then I have to groupByKey and reduce or aggregate my data to rebuild the input data with the persons name.

In fact, it's work but I'm not sure that it's the best way to do this and I prefer to avoid internal kafka storage for reduce and aggregation operations.

Does someone have a better idea ?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The approach is sound.

If your KTable data is small, you can consider using a `GlobalKTable` for the join. This allows to use non-key fields from the KStream to do lookups into the `GlobalKTable`.